# webkit browser doesn't completely load image

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I'm building a site for a client and i've come across an issue where in a webkit browser the images dont fully load. so chrome and safari, on mac and ipad.
http://coatesconstruction.co.uk

I've done some research previously and i found an article suggesting that webkit browsers open multiple connections up per image to download them and i wondered if this couldnt be the issue.

one of the aims with this site was to make the right column fluid, such that if the user resized the browser the image showing grew, which has meant the backend is saving images at 1600px wide and im using width: 100% to make them autosize to the left column. 
This means the images are pretty massive on the server, is it anything to do with the size which is stopping chrome and safari from showing them?

Comment: I changed the height of the `div.slideshow` to 583px (it was 4px beforehand), and the images appeared fully. This is a css problem.

Comment: I'm trying to use jquery to get the height of the image. im using the cycle plugin to change the images. using the after event i do this. i can hardcode the height and prove that in firefox it changes the height of the container, which allows the image to show, even adds a gap at the bottom when i hardcode it too big.

it just doesn't affect the container in webkit browsers. tried resetting the css on both .slideshow and .col1. using firebug to check its working.

                $('.col1').css('height', function(){
                    return $('this').height();
                });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does load the entire image.

You have messed up somewhere in the CSS code and that's why the entire image doesn't show up on Webkit browsers.

Try setting div#col1's height to 656px (or what ever height you want!) and you will see the entire image.

Comment: kind of this one, thanks.

though i've now discovered that the second time around the rotation of the slideshow it fails to load only the first image in webkit.

Answer (score 2):

um, the images are loading fine, the issue is that you're cropping them :)

```
.col1, .col2, .col3 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Since all your images have `position:absolute` set, they won't force the parent container to get any larger, so your parent is stuck at 124px high.

Comment: They work fine on 2nd load because `div.slideshow` has a height of `1459px` tacked on to it.  The images are loading fine, they're being cropped

Answer (score 1):

```
.leftmenu .col1 {
    height: 765px;
}
```